# Unable to compile java class file in cmd

Tags: java, cmd

I am in `c:\new\control` folder and want to execute `c:\hello.java`

I am trying `c:\new\control> javac c:\hello.java`

Its creating class file but  `c:\new\control> java hello` is giving me `Error:could not find o load main class hello`

```
In simple way i wan ask , i have class file in c:\ (say c:\hello.class)
I am in c:\user, how can i execute it???
```

Comment: This is probably a classpath issue. In which package did you put your `hello.java` ?

Comment: its not in any package, its in c:\

Comment: @posix: Packages aren't the same as directories. Does your source code have a `package` statement at the top?

Comment: @Jon nope its in default package

Comment: @posix: Then what I've shown should work absolutely fine. You'll need to give more details - including where class files are generated, the error message etc. It would help if you'd show your source, too... I've been *assuming* that `hello.java` contains the class declaration for `hello`... is that the case?

Answer (score 3):

By default, the .class file will be generated alongside the .java file. Options:

- Use `-d .` when compiling to generate the classes relative to the current directory (including creating subdirectories for packages):

  ```
  > javac -d . c:\hello.java
  > java hello
  ```
- Specify a classpath when running:

  ```
  > java c:\hello.java
  > java -cp c:\ hello
  ```

Comment: not working , may be that work well in package structure,  i wan run my class file which is in c:\ from other place like c:\noname\

Comment: @posix: Well then the second solution should work. It really doesn't help that you haven't shown any of the code - and "not working" doesn't give us much clue what you can see, either. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: am tryin to run java prog from another java prog, Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac C:\\Hello.java "); this is working but Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java C:\\Hello "); is not working, i tried Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd c:\\ & java C:\\Hello "); but "cd" cmd is not working

Comment: @posix: I wish you'd said that before. That's a *completely different problem*. You should basically use `ProcessBuilder` and set the working directory instead. `cd` isn't a binary you can execute; it's part of the command shell. Please learn from this that it's *crucial* to give context when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created class with different name in your file hello.java.  So, try to find out class file with the name of class you mentioned in hello.java file after compilation.